# Why are victims of Covid19 being wrapped in plastic?

Tags: virology, infection, death, coronavirus

Several articles describe the unique ways Covid-19 patients are being buried.

For example, in this [Reuters article](https://uk.reuters.com/article/us-health-coronavirus-israel/israel-steps-up-testing-as-coronavirus-detections-rise-idUKKBN21514R) about Israel:

> These included decontaminating and hermetically wrapping bodies in
>   double layers of polyethylene. For Jewish dead, ritual washing of the
>   body would be conducted in one of four special stations in the
>   country, the document showed.

And this [LA Times article](https://www.latimes.com/world-nation/story/2020-03-18/coronavirus-deaths-in-iran-lead-to-mass-burial-pits-for-victims-families-it-is-changing-the-way-they-mourn) about Iran:

> Nor are they wrapped in traditional white cloth. They are covered in
>   hospital plastic, marking them as victims — both young and old — of
>   the coronavirus.

People die from viruses all the time but I've never heard of victims being buried in this way. What is unique about Covid-19 ?

Answer (score 5):

The [WHO guidelines](https://www.who.int/csr/resources/publications/ebola/whoemcesr982sec7-9.pdf) for [VHF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viral_hemorrhagic_fever) victims (Ebola etc.) do say that they should be buried in body bags, and if those are not available, in plastic sheeting.

> If body bags are not available, wrap the body in two
>   thickness of cotton cloth and soak with 1:10 bleach
>   solution. Then wrap the body in plastic sheeting. Seal the
>   wrapping with plastic tape. Spray the body bag as in
>   Step 3. Place the body in a coffin if one is available.

Obviously some are treating covid-19 victims with the same amount of caution. I can't tell you at the moment if this is justified or not.

Comment: I suppose we might see [copper-lined](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/21556/have-there-been-any-practical-applications-devised-for-the-observation-that-copp) coffins soon.